# Is there an annotation tool for instance segmentation on Ipad?

Tags: ipad, deep-learning, pytorch, image-annotations

**Is there an annotation tool to produce multi layer (for overlapping objects within the image) and pixel exact image annotations on IPad?**

*Background to my question:*

There a lot of annotation tools for Linux and Windows
(e.g. the ones listed here: https://www.v7labs.com/blog/best-image-annotation-tools
or here: https://humansintheloop.org/10-of-the-best-open-source-annotation-tools-for-computer-vision-2021/)

I haven't tried all of them, but non of them seem to be available for the IPad.

I am using the Ipad to make image annotations because it is faster for me to annotate with a stylus than with a mouse on the PC (also I can do annotations when I am not in the office). Further, most annotation tools feel clunky and too overloaded with bureaucracy (this is only my subjective opinion).

I am currently using Adobe Fresco (sucks only because its not open source and a little expensive), which works well in combination with a small script, that I wrote to convert the .psd files into torch tensors.

My workflow with Fresco is fast and the annotations are very precise. However, I was bashed by a reviewer when submitting a paper mentioning that the annotations were produced with Fresco. The paper was rejected because the reviewer thought annotating images with fresco was ridiculous and that there are supposedly much better alternatives (which he did not mention)... and which I am still too dump to find. Any suggestions?

Comment: Honestly that may be more a framing issue, just bury that detail and say "ground truth segmentation masks were manually annotated by human annotators using a graphical user interface" or something to that effect. It's a dumb reason for the reviewer to be upset if the final product is the same